# Setting an image's alpha value (via PIL/Pillow)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a base image, on top of which, I'm trying to paste a black strip with 50% alpha. Here's what I've been testing:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

base_width, base_height = base_img.size
if base_img.mode != 'RGB':
    base_img = base_img.convert("RGB")
black_strip = Image.new('RGBA', (base_width, 20),(0,0,0,128)) #creating the black strip
offset = (0,base_height/2)
base_img.paste(background,offset)
```

The resulting black strip does NOT have alpha transparency; it is entirely solid. Example:

[image]

Can someone help me improve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noticed, `Image.paste` ignores the alpha channel of the pasted image. However, it does take an optional `mask` parameter. This accepts an RGBA image as input, extracting its alpha channel, so you should be able to just pass in the pasted image again:

```
base_img.paste(black_strip, offset, black_strip)
```

This also makes it easy to generate a mask if the original image didn't have one. For example, the following will paste an RGB image but make the black regions of it transparent:

```
mask = rgb_img.point(lambda i: min(i * 25, 255)).
base_img.paste(rgb_img, offset, mask)
```

**PS** The above advice only works if the the base image had no alpha channel (its mode was RGB, not RGBA). Otherwise you should probably use `Image.alpha_composite` to combine the images instead, though annoyingly you may first have to pad or crop the pasted image so that it's the same size as the base image.

Comment: Thanks for this. Being new to image processing, I was also wondering if you could shed a bit of a light on the uses of image masking (in the way you've generated it).

Comment: Mask here is just Pillow's term for alpha channel, in which the value of each pixel indicates how transparent it is. To compose combine two images you can either use an alpha channel already associated with one of them (like in your example) or create your own mask.